# Varying Sized Array as Function Input in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently working on a function that I wish to accept various array lengths as inputs. For example, let's say I have a function called 'sum'. Ideally, I would want to feed this function an array of ints that can vary in size (i.e. one call will sum [1, 2, 3, 4] and another call may sum [1, 1, 1].

What is the best practice for achieving this? I had attempted declaring a function as

```
 int sum(int array[]);
```

but this throws a compiler error saying that the length of the argument array must be specified.

Would it be better practice to use a reference to a pointer titled array along with a length specifier that would be used as iterator? As in

```
 int sum(const int*& array, int lengthArray);
```

With this approach, I assume it would be possible to get access to the values of the array, and then be able to cycle through elements using the length of the array as another argument. However, I am not confident if my logic regarding the pointer and reference is on track with 'good code'.

I don't have the means to try this until I get home from work, but the problem has been on my mind ever since it came up. So I thought I would pose the question regarding what the best practice is.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a good time to read up on [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: It's not C++, it's plain old C. Forget about C.

Comment: Let me give slightly different advice: don't do this yourself at all. Use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) instead.

Answer (score 4):

As a C++ beginner use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for variable length arrays, and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for fixed size arrays.

Comment: I would have jumped right to std::vector, but I've heard that using that as a data type can be very inefficient when your elements aren't primitive data types. The 'sum' example I used above what just a simple example. Would you still recommend using std::vector if the elements were heavy weight objects?

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd give the same advice, as [@Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) does.

> However, I am not confident if my logic regarding the pointer and reference is on track with 'good code'.

The use of a reference isn't really needed, it would be sufficient to write

```
 int sum(const int* array, int lengthArray);
```

Use references for pointers where you want to change these from inside the function (e.g. for allocating memory).

Comment: I should have specified, I want my function to have access to the array elements, but I do not want the function to change the values of the elements. Does using a const in the context you did still protect the function from changing values?

Answer (score -1):

You could use `std::vector` as was suggested, but if you do need to use the C array, you can do this:

```
int sum(int* array, unsigned int len)
```

or just

```
int sum(int* array)
```

if you use a special value (e.g INT_MAX) to make the end of the array. In C array and pointer are essentially the same thing.

Comment: `template<size_t N> int sum(int (&array)[N])` is better, but using a `std::vector` or `std::array` is better still

Comment: @Kevin there is `std::accumulate` in `<algorithms>`, so there is no need for such a function :-)

Comment: True, but pointer vs vector vs array apply to more than just sum functions